# Andengine Game moving background

Tags: andengine

AndEngine: I want to make an autoparallaxBackground using 5 sprites. These 5 sprites to be in linear arrangement and it should repeat 1st sprite after completing last sprite. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
background_scene = new AutoParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, 20f);
background_scene.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-5.0f,
            new Sprite(Constants.CW / 2 + 150, Constants.CH / 2 + 70,
                    your background Textureregion, vbom)));
```